# Selenium Attribute Error when selecting dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I had some code that was running fine but has recently ran into an error. When I run the following code to select the dropdown to iterate through pages, it returns this error:

```
File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\shawn\documents\python scripts\webscraping\basketball\nba stats scrape daily update.py:42
select = Select(browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="DropDown_select__4pIg9"))

File C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py:36 in __init__
if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tag_name'.
```

If I change this line to:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="DropDown_select__4pIg9")['ELEMENT'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\shawn\documents\python scripts\webscraping\basketball\nba stats scrape daily update.py:42
select = Select(browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="DropDown_select__4pIg9")['ELEMENT'])

File C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py:36 in __init__
if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Any help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import lxml
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
#os.chdir(r'C:\Users\shawn\Documents\Python Scripts\Webscraping')
directory = os.getcwd() 

beginningTime = time.time()
 
##Change the file path to where your chromedriver.exe file is
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Temp\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
 
url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/players/boxscores'
 
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()

x = 1
dfStats = []

for x in range(50):
    x+=1
    time.sleep(10)
    print(x)
    select = Select(browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="DropDown_select__4pIg9"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(str(x))
    table = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Crom_table__p1iZz').get_attribute('outerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html.parser')
    dfData = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
    print(dfData.head())
    print(dfData.shape)
    dfStats.append(dfData)
print(dfStats)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few issues.

1. You don't need to increment `x` using `x+=1`, etc. You can increment using the `for`.

   ```
   for x in range(1, 50):
   ```
2. I added a wait after the new dropdown selection is made because the page needs a sec to load

   ```
   table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz'))
   ```
3. As of Selenium v4.6+, you no longer need to specify your driver path. [DriverManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager) takes care of that now

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   ```
4. ... and I cleaned up some other assorted stuff

The updated code

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

#os.chdir(r'C:\Users\shawn\Documents\Python Scripts\Webscraping')
directory = os.getcwd() 

beginningTime = time.time()

url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/players/boxscores'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)

dfStats = []

select = Select(browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU select.DropDown_select__4pIg9"))
for x in range(1, 5):
    print(x)
    select.select_by_visible_text(str(x))
    table = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'html.parser')
    dfData = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
    print(dfData.head())
    print(dfData.shape)
    dfStats.append(dfData)
print(dfStats)
```

Comment: I'll take a look at your revised code and give feedback later tonight.  My initial response though is that the select option isn't related to the year, but is related to the page number. Ideally, this is run every day, or every few days and therefore I don't need every page every time. That is why the it was expecting 1 or 2, etc. I haven't doubled checked to make sure the dropdowns were different, so maybe that is inadvertently referring to the year dropdown. I previously had it pointed to the xpath, but changed that as I was working to resolve my errors over the past day or so.

Comment: I just looked and the class name is the same, so it'll have to be converted back to xpath. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see what you mean... you were trying to select pages from the "Page" dropdown. I thought you were wanting to cycle through the SEASON dropdown. I'll fix this and update in a min.

Comment: Updated answer. This is now cycling through the Page dropdown values

Comment: JeffC - I still get the error before the loop.   File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\shawn\documents\python scripts\webscraping\basketball\nba stats scrape daily update.py:33
    select = Select(browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU select.DropDown_select__4pIg9"))

  File C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py:36 in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Comment: I think I fixed it. I mistakenly put `driver` instead of `browser` as the driver variable name in part of the code. Check the updated answer. This code, as is, works without issue on my box.

Comment: I had already fixed that on my end so it doesn't seem to be that. It must be an issue on my end with selenium because I have another script that is running into a similar issue. It seems that when I find an element, it is returning a dictionary. What version of selenium are you using? I think I recently upgraded, and am wondering if I should downgrade to an earlier version.

Comment: Some google searching has pointed to an outdated version of the chromedriver. I'll update that as well and see if that resolves the issue or not.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that this change shouldn't have caused that error anyway but I was hopeful. I would use the latest and greatest selenium but maybe wipe everything and reinstall might help.

Comment: An outdated ChromeDriver wouldn't cause this issue. You would immediately get a driver mismatch error and the script would stop.

Comment: I've updated my chromedriver and it seems to work on my other script. I'm running into an lxml issue even though I do have lxml installed. However, I'll troubleshoot that and see if I can get that fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do have the latest selenium - I had upgraded that recently. However, my chromedriver was back from 2018 and this did seem to be the fix. For others that encounter this issue, this is some back and forth on the issue - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9978